# How to know whether a file is completely written using PHP?

Tags: php

I am writing a SQL query results to a file and once I am done writing it to a file I need to output the file to user for download. My Question is how do i know when the file is completely written as different SQL query takes different amount of time. Is there anyway I can know that a file is completely written  using PHP ?

Comment: you want to know it in the same php script or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks a lot of details, so I don't think a definitive answer can be given.

If the file system you are using allows you to open a file with exclusive write access, then the query script can open the file in that way, and then on the other script you simply try to open the file with write access repeatedly until the call succeeds, at which point you know the other process closed it.

Assuming the above is not possible, another option is to implement some mechanism by which the query script can signal to the other script that the writing is complete. For example, you could write some sort of marker as the last line of the file, something that is guaranteed to never appear as part of the output of the SQL query.

I hope this helps. If it doesn't, you may want to add more details to your question so that the problem can be understood better.

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing the SQL query results to a file?

If you are using a PHP stream perhaps look at the set_stream_blocking function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php), particularly at the note about using fwrite and checking for the return value that lets you know how much data has been written

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple processes able to write to the same file then I would say no, you can't say whether the file is completely written or not. Is like asking to know whether a log file is completely written or not - a thing which usually doesn't happen.

However, if there are some cases when you know that the file is completely written (let's say for example when the file reaches a certain size, or some amount of queries are written to it), then you could use some flags - you change the value of the flag when the condition is met, and display the file to the user when the flag has certain value